# Conditional count based on second variable

Tags: r, conditional

I'm still somewhat new to  R, so please bear with me. I'm trying to summarize the results of the variable riskT0. However, because I have some missing values in the variable riskT2 I would like to only include participant values if they have also a value for the riskT2 variable.

reproducible example:

```
ID <- c(1:300) #participants
group <- c(1:2) #there are two groups
riskT0 <- c(1:2) #value of 1st measurement
riskT2 <- c(1:3) #value of 2nd measurement 
df<- data.frame(ID,group,riskT0,riskT2) #create df
df["riskT2"][df["riskT2"] == 3] <- "NA" #create NAs (I'm sure there are better ways)
```

What is the simplest way to summarize the riskT0 variable if a riskT2 value is available?
Also how to do the same but then do it separately for group 1 and 2?

The way I was trying to get the results so far was the following:

```
"count(df$riskT0[df$riskT2 !=NA])
```

which doesn't work. Also I wouldn't know how to filter for group.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set `"NA"` as a string. Set it as its own type `NA`:

`df["riskT2"][df["riskT2"] == 3] <- NA`

This does not change the type of the other values: as you have it, riskT2 changes type from integer to character after assignment of `"NA"`.

Then, to address your question, you need to use `is.na(x)` to check for NA values in a variable `x`.

For a count of all riskT0 values conditioned on the riskT2 being NA you would write:

`table(df$riskT0[!is.na(df$riskT2)])`

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thank you! Would it be possible to also add another condition in this code like  'group ==1' to show the output only of group 1 or 2?

Comment: You can use a logical vector (TRUE/FALSE) to select the elements of a vector you're interested in. Above, we used `!is.na(...)`. To _also_ select group 1, modify that logical vector: `!is.na(df$riskT2) & df$group == 1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to summarize `riskT0` you can do

```
with(subset(df, df$riskT2 != "NA"), summary(riskT0))
```

`subset` creates new dataframe out from `df` by eliminating all the rows of `df` where riskT2 takes `NA`. Passing this temporary dataframe to `with` hepls at making the variable `riskT0` available for `summary`.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason it didn't work though. The output returns simply:
```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
```


without showing any output.

Comment: ops! replace NA by "NA".

Comment: Thank you it works now. However, because my data is based on count variables it seems like table() is more appropriate for my data.

with() returns the following output:
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    1.0     1.0     1.5     1.5     2.0     2.0

Comment: if you want a the frequency distribution, just replace `summary` by `table`. In the post you talk about "I'm trying to summarize the results of the variable riskT0.", and `summary` does that.